Difference between int function and "// " (getting only integer part) in python
I was just trying to solve a beginner level problem in geekforgeeks which was a lcm and gcd problem
In my first attempt I tried this to get the lcm of A and B: int((A*B)/gcd), but i failed in one of the test cases. This one to be specific -
For input: A = 405448323, B = 435638250
Expected output was: 58876265965718250 for the lcm part
But my code returned this: 58876265965718248
But then i changed my code a bit to be: (A*B)//gcd
And this passed all the test cases
According to my understanding the int function should discard the decimal part of the number and return the integer and using '//' should also do the same, but it seems like they are a bit different.
I tried to search the web to find how they different but couldn't find anything relevant. Can someone help me with this?

Hint: what result do you get from int(float(58876265965718250))? Can you think of a reason for this? If not, check the duplicate links. Also, think more carefully about your reasoning: "According to my understanding the int function should discard the decimal part of the number" - if you understand the underlying math, then you should understand that there would not ever be a decimal part from this division. So the problem is the other thing that goes wrong with floating-point numbers.
